# Cannot logout with Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I cannot logout a user.

I ported custom user management logic over to a Symfony 4 project. It uses recipes for `security` and `guard`.

Here is the `logout` config in my main firewall:

```
    logout:
        path: /logout
        target: /
```

Result:
- User goes to /logout
- User is redirected to /
- `is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED")` continues to return `true` in my template (`false` is expected)

Other Considerations:
- The firewall entry is getting triggered because I get errors if I remove it
- I have tried adding additional parameters to `logout` to destroy the session and cookies, however that made no difference
- Logging in works fine

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

:: edit - added `security.yaml` as requested ::

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User: bcrypt
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    providers:
        app_users:
            entity: { class: App\Entity\User, property: email }
        app_oauth:
            id: app.oauth_user_provider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            provider: app_users
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    google: "/login/check-google"
                default_target_path: /
                login_path: /
                failure_path: /login
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: app.oauth_user_provider
            remember_me:
                secret: "%env(APP_SECRET)%"
                lifetime: 2592000
                path:  /
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
                entry_point: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            switch_user: ~
```

Comment: Hello, can you show us your `config/packages/security.yaml` file ?

Comment: @MatMouth Yes, I just added it, thanks for looking.

Comment: You don't have any access_control to authorize page for anonymous user
`access_control:
        - { path: ^/login/check-google, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

Comment: What was the final solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `serialize` and `unserialize` methods for field `$this->email` in `App\Entity\User`.

Answer (score 6):

**Add these commands**

**In security.yaml**

```
logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: true
```

**In controller**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {

    }
```

**In logout button**

```
<a class="text-muted" href="{{ path('logout') }}">logout </a>
```

Comment: That is true by default: `https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewalls`

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208429/cant-logout-user-in-symfony4/58703592#58703592)

I'll repeat what worked for me:

If you follow the instructions at [Symfony Security Logging Out](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#logging-out), make sure you use the proper route name to get to /logout. I had to use 'app_logout' to actually get it to logout and I was not able to change that path name in the Security.yaml file without also modifying the controller annotations (see below). No controller needed. No custom handler needed (thank god).

After you configure logout, try running `php bin/console debug:router` to check the actual route to /logout.

The logout part of my Security.yaml looked like this:

```
logout:
    path: app_logout
    # where to redirect after logout
    target: front
```

Based on instructions, I added an empty controller (if you want custom path names, you'll have to change the path names here plus add the change to Security.yaml):

```
<?php

//App/Controller/SecurityController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \Exception('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall');
    }
}
```

My call looked like this:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('app_logout') }}">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes with `php bin/console debug:router`.

For me the security_logout created in the security controller was being called first. I simple removed the function from security controller and it worked (remove the annotation too)